7,8,9 & 0 keys stopped working on my laptop after trying to fix a bad shim signature error
I'm working around this problem by using the on-screen accessibility virtual keyboard.
But after recent attempts to try to fix a bad shim signature error, the 7,8,9 & 0 keys stopped working on my laptop keyboard. I was not able to resolve the bad shim signature, but was able to work around it by disabling secure boot.
My first priority is to fix the keyboard. But I also want to fix the bad shim signature so I can use secure boot once the keyboard is working again. Expert help would be much appreciated since I am way out of my depth as a non-tech person.
Here are my system details:
System Details Report

Report details

Date generated:                              2024-12-16 15:41:51

Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              Microsoft Corporation Surface Book 2
Memory:                                      16.0 GiB
Processor:                                   Intel® Core™ i7-8650U × 8
Graphics:                                    Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)
Graphics 1:                                  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060
Disk Capacity:                               256.1 GB

Software Information:

Firmware Version:                            394.779.768
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               46
Windowing System:                            X11
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.12.3-surface-2


Can you run a diagnostic test from your firmware? Does that test for your keyboard test? Fix common problems using the Surface app and Surface Diagnostic Toolkit

I installed Linux Ubuntu without dual boot, so I don't have access to Microsoft apps or that toolkit.

The first comment made me search for "Surface firmware Linux" and I found this: github.com/linux-surface/surface-uefi-firmware
When I followed the steps, it resolved the issue and all the keys on my laptop were once again working. But the next day after a reboot, I was back to the 7890 keys not working again.
